# React Native / Flatlist keyExtractor

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use this json array as an input for my Flatlist (this is an output of my Realm query) :

```
[
    {
        "0": {
            "id": "Id 1",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "body": "Body 1"
        },
        "1": {
            "id": "Id 2",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "body": "Body 2"
        }
    }
]
```

My problem is that I do not know how to setup the keyExtractor and display the title and the body of each item. The first node of my json array changes at every child : 0 then 1 then 2 and that I have not seen this situation on any other example on the internet.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={item => item}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.noteElementTitle} >{item.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.noteElementBody} >{item.body}</Text>
        </View>
    )}
/>
```

Comment: I think that your model is wrong. It seems that you are using an array of length 1 which is composed of by a map with two entries as data, while FlatList expect just an array. See doc @ https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html.
What if you use something like 

    [
        {
            "id": "Id 1",
            "title": "Title 1",
            "body": "Body 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "Id 2",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "body": "Body 2"
        }
    ]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I achieved to make it works with this array : [ { "note": { "id": 1, "title": "Note 1 Title", "body": "Note 1 body" } }, { "note": { "id": 2, "title": "Note 2 Title", "body": "Note 2 body" } } ]. It has the same format as the one I want to use now, the only difference is that the first child is the same here so it is easy to set up the keyExtractor.